# How to resize a note in a Visio 2010 UML diagram

Tags: uml, diagram, visio

I have added a note with about 50 lines of text to an UML diagram in Visio 2010, and I can't resize the shape. I can see connection points, but not the blue ones that you can drag to resize the shape. Modifying the height manually through View menu, Task Panes, Size & Position, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A note usually can only be resize to the minimum size of the letters inside. I mean that you resize the size of caracters or the shape of the note  in order to get the smaller rectangle or square and the note should automatically resize themselves. If not this is a bug !!

Comment: I have added the Developer tab to the Visio 2010 ribbon, then unchecked all the items in the Protection button, and I can see now the blue squares around the shape that indicate that you can resize it, but I cannot move them.

Comment: This is therefore a bug. Report it and if you are lucky God (e.g. Microsoft) will fix it sooner or later.

Answer (score 5):

You can format the text using <kbd>shift</kbd> / <kbd>enter</kbd> for line breaks to change the shape of the text which will change the shape of the box. Not elegant but workable.

Answer (score 3):

Tested and works in Visio 2010

i. Select the shape

1. Select the Developer ribbon. (You may need to make this visible by right clicking on the ribbon>Customize the Ribbon> Tick the Developer box)
2. (Developer ribbon) From "Shape Design" select "Protection".  Untick both Width & Height
3. (Developer ribbon) From "Shape Design" select "Show ShapeSheet" > "Shape"
4. Within the "Shape Transform" table remove "GUARD" from the width and height cells

N.B This will work for with a singly selected shape, not a group.  By copying the modified shape the shapes settings will remain with the copy although this seems to result in the text field in the copy being uneditable.

Comment: This works for other shapes, but not the Note -- Right Click the note and select UNGROUP before doing any of this. It will be converted to a normal shape and won't be a UML note anymore, but it will look like it and that's probably good enough.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.softwarestencils.com/uml/#Visio2010 fixed this problem for me. If you want to have complete control over the formatting, this is the "only" way (at least that I've found) that doesn't cost anything.